# Excel using proper formula, Lookup vs Vlookup vs IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

Trying to write a formula for Excel, Using 2 worksheets. to classify the invoices

Worksheet 1 has Group Name and Group ID

Worksheet 2 has Group Name, invoice amount,invoice number

Trying to get the Group ID to worksheet 2, keeping in mind a ID can be use multiple times

Using formula below but the IDs I'm getting back aren't matching

```
=LOOKUP(F2,GROUP!C:C,ID!B:B)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `vlookup` you have to be sure that your data is first sorted, otherwise the algorithm tends to fail.

A better alternative, in my experience, is to do something like the following. I am assuming that Worksheet 1 has `Group Name` in Column A and `Group ID` in column B, and that Worksheet 2 has `Group Name` in column A. This formula would go in worksheet 2, in a blank column starting in row 2:

```
=index(Worksheet1!B:B, match(A2, Worksheet1!A:A, 0))
```

If you fill that equation all the way down, then it will perform the equivalent to a `vlookup` but without the need to sort your data first.

Comment: VLOOKUP does not need to be sorted if you use the forth criteria as false.  Then it looks for an exact match, like you are doing with the third criteria in your match formula.

Comment: I see. learn something new every day. I do feel like I've tried using that flag in the VLOOKUP formula before, though, and that it has failed me. Perhaps I am mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GroupName is column 1 of Worksheet2 and that GroupName and ID are in columns A and B, respectively in Worksheet1

Place this formula in B1 of Worksheet2:

```
=vlookup(A1,Worksheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

Update all cell references and placements as they match your actual sheet data.

Answer (score 0):

In Worksheet2:

```
=Vlookup(F2,Worksheet1!B:C,2,False)
```

But it would be better to size the table exactly and not refer to the whole column, like:

```
=Vlookup(F2,Worksheet1!B1:C200,2,False)
```